# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when run my simple code

Tags: java

i write a simple code to understanding passing value manually, there is my code

```
public class coba{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int a;
        int b;
        a= Integer.parseInt(args [0]);
        b= Integer.parseInt(args [1]);

        int c=0;
        c= a+b;
        System.out.println("jumlah "+c);
    }
}
```

why i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException?? 
and how to solve that so i can pass the values of a and b manually? 
thanks for the answer :)

Comment: did you run with command `java coba 10,20` like this

Comment: are you passing any arguments!show us the arguments you are passing

Comment: Also, please read [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it seems it will benefit you in the long term.

Comment: OMG...., i really miss that..., i only run with java coba..., very big thanks @Prabhker :)

Comment: @Anirud..., i miss passing the value, i think the values will passed after i run java coba, but actually not.

Comment: @ppeterka i get error 404 when opening that link :(

Comment: @adhit_yogapratama Strange, it works for me. [This one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) is one step closer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well presumably you're not passing in two command-line arguments. It should be fine if you run it with:

```
java coba 10 20
```

for example.

You can validate this at the start using `args.length`:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("I need two command line arguments!");
        return;
    }
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int c = a + b;
    System.out.println("jumlah "+c);
}
```

Comment: Reputationhunter :) ... just realized your "all time" rank. (this comment isn't meant to be offencive)

Comment: hahaha..., no @Jon Skeet, actually i'm not..., i think that i must pass the value after i run java coba, by the way thaks for the answer :)

Comment: ehh... sory..., i mean @Loki, not jon skeet :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[] args){ // here args= String[0]

}
```

So

```
    a= Integer.parseInt(args [0]); // these are not valid
    b= Integer.parseInt(args [1]);
```

Comment: so if i want to initialize a and b--> (String [2] args)??

Answer (score 1):

to run your program you should pass two parameter from console/command prompt

```
javac coba.java
```

after that

```
java coba 5 8
```

Comment: yes..., it works..., i miss that values..., i think i must pass the parameter after run the java coba then i pass the value..., :) thanks